# How to calculate sum of current week for every row in sql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
        update_time         | daily_profit 
----------------------------+---------------------------
 2021-02-26 00:33:00.13055  |    0.1
 2021-02-27 14:23:18.173233 |    0.2
 2021-02-28 00:33:00.13055  |    0.4
 2021-03-01 01:31:00.146775 |    0.2
```

I have a postgres table `profits` as above, one row one day.

How can I calculate the sum of current week for every row in sql? Like the output as below:

```
        update_time         |    running_total
----------------------------+---------------------------
 2021-02-26 00:33:00.13055  |    0.1
 2021-02-27 14:23:18.173233 |    0.3   // 0.1 + 0.2
 2021-02-28 00:33:00.13055  |    0.4   // 0.4, new week 
 2021-03-01 01:31:00.146775 |    0.6   // 0.4 + 0.2
```

The question may turn into another question, how to pass a value of current row to sub query?

```
select update_time,
(select sum(daily_profit) from profits where update_time > (select DATE_TRUNC('WEEK', <update_time_of_current_row>)) and update_time < (select DATE_TRUNC('WEEK', <update_time_of_current_row>) + INTERVAL '7 DAY'))
from profits;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
select p.*,
       sum(daily_profit) over (partition by date_trunc('week', update_time) order by update_time) as running_weekly_profit
from profits p;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=740115c1b20753692d2b5367a2bc3ee6) is a db<>fiddle.

The above starts the week on Monday, which is pretty standard.  If you want Sunday:

```
select p.*,
       sum(daily_profit) over (partition by date_trunc('week', update_time + interval '1 day') order by update_time) as running_weekly_profit
from profits p;
```

Comment: One more question, how to calculate the running total with `sum over` without partition? I do this using `COALESCE(daily_profit + lag(daily_profit, 1) over (order by update_time), 0)`.

Comment: `sum(daily_profit) over(partition by 1 order by update_time)`?

Comment: Just remove the `partition by`:  `sum(daily_profit) over (order by update_time)`.